# Unix Timestamp in seconds to C# DateTime is not UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, unix, epoch, date-conversion

<s>I am aware that Unix Timestamp are UTC in nature</s> (misleading, this is not true, `new Date()` will always be on the browser/server timezone, and `.getTime()` reflects that).

How come when converting to a C# DateTime is is not UTC.

I've converted the date August, 9 2092 to timespamp in seconds (3869074800),

```
new Date('August, 9 2092').getTime()/1000
```

or https://codepen.io/pnmcosta/pen/rpvjVp

But when converting to a C# date, it's not UTC (8/8/2092 11:00:00 PM)? Even though the EPOCH has been created as UTC:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public readonly static DateTime EPOCH_UNIX = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    private readonly static double MaxUnixSeconds = (DateTime.MaxValue.ToUniversalTime() - EPOCH_UNIX).TotalSeconds;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FromUnixTimeStamp(3869074800));
    }

    public static DateTime FromUnixTimeStamp(long value)
    {
        return value > MaxUnixSeconds ? EPOCH_UNIX.AddMilliseconds(value) : EPOCH_UNIX.AddSeconds(value);
    }
}
```

or https://dotnetfiddle.net/ERySea

How best to handle this scenario, bearing in mind that time is not of importance, but the day should be correct?

EDIT 2

Think I may have hacked the date to figure out the offset (updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/ERySea) to:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public readonly static DateTime EPOCH_UNIX = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    private readonly static long MaxUnixSeconds = (long)(DateTime.MaxValue.ToUniversalTime() - EPOCH_UNIX).TotalSeconds;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // date with DST (Daylight savings time), e.g. 08/09/2092 (DD/MM/yyyy) 
        // is stored as, e.g. 3869074800 seconds, from EPOCH_UNIX
        // instead of 3869078400 (UTC, without offsets) as it should be!
        DateTime dt = FromUnixTimeStamp(3869074800);
        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}", dt);

        // fix DST offset
        if (dt.Hour != 0)
        {
            int offset = 24 - dt.Hour;
            dt = dt.AddHours(offset);
            Console.WriteLine("Offset: {0}", offset);
        }

        // fix century (if date of birth)
        if (dt.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year)
            dt = dt.AddYears(-100);

        Console.WriteLine("Fixed Date: {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}", dt);
    }

    public static DateTime FromUnixTimeStamp(long value)
    {
        return value > MaxUnixSeconds ? EPOCH_UNIX.AddMilliseconds(value) : EPOCH_UNIX.AddSeconds(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php August 9, 2092 00:00:00 is 3869078400 , not ... 4800 and 3869074800 is indeed 8/8/2092 11:00:00 PM UTC

Comment: Using a double for the amount of seconds looks suspicious. I would recommend using long, especially with values this big.

Comment: @Fildor, so how come new Date('August, 9 2092').getTime()/1000 is incorrect if getTime() is meant to return the timestamp in UTC?

Comment: I don't know. The point is: Your code might be correct. It just had the wrong input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is JavaScript not C#, or more correctly your premise what `new Date('August, 9 2092').getTime()/1000` represents.

JavaScript will create a new Date as being in local time zone not UTC. So

```
new Date('August, 9 2092')
```

is actually

```
Sat Aug 09 2092 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Notice the offset? This is actually `Fri Aug 08 2092 23:00:00 UTC+0000` so the epoch you get from JavaScript is not what you intended.

You should ***subtract*** the timezone offset (in minutes multiplied by 60) to get UTC though.

```
var date = new Date('August, 9 2092');
var timestamp = date.getTime()/1000 - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60;
// timestamp == 3869078400
```

**EDIT**

Rather than fudging the calculation, you'd be better off assuming the timestamp is local...

Change

```
public readonly static DateTime EPOCH_UNIX = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

to

```
public readonly static DateTime EPOCH_UNIX = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

At least then the result is `08 Aug 2092 23:00 Local`.

Comment: ok, makes sense, new Date is local time. however, how to I in C# ensure I convert the timestamp? unfortunately I cannot change the source of the timestamp, it's from a service provider.

Comment: yah, I'm aware the problem is the Javascript, however it's unlikely that I can change that as it comes from a service provider.

Comment: @PedroCosta What you are doing is correct from C#. Garbage in, garbage out. As Derek noted the timestamp in your code (3869074800) is not midnight (UTC). If this is what you have and there's no possibility to change it then there's not a lot you can do other than assume that it's local time (GMT) and fudge accordingly.

Comment: I think I might have hacked it, see my edit, what's your take on it?

Comment: if the timestamp represents GMT+0000 (non DST) the hour `dt.Hour` is going to be zero and now you've got the time 24 hours later. You'd be better off assuming the timestamp is localtime and that it's GMT.

Comment: exactly, just did a second edit with that in mind. thank you so much, I will assign yours as the answer as you were clearer with the cause and effect.

Comment: just noticed your edit now, thanks however that won't suit, this is actually being imported into a WinForms Remotely Distributed APP in C# .net 3.5, and may be used downunder too :) #TimeZoneMindWarp :D

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.epochconverter.com/ the UNIX timestamp of 3869074800 is 8/8/2092 11:00:00 PM, so C# is correctly displaying it in GMT.  UTC and GMT are... not the same, but for the purposes of a human reading it it's accurate to say that you can treat them as the same.

Your problem lies in how you got the UNIX timestamp of 3869074800.

Comment: that's precisely my point, how come if the timestamp 3869074800 is UTC but on C# is is not... I need the c# to return the 9th not 8th at 11PM

Comment: document.write(new Date(3869074800 *1000)) return the date as expected..

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it more clear.  3869074800 is not the correct UNIX timestamp.  It may be converting back-and-forth properly using whatever it is that you're getting it from (doesn't appear to be something built-in to C#?) but it is not UTC.

Comment: correct, it's a SaaS product (Agile CRM) the dates are stored in timestamp, I guess they are not storing it in UTC then.